# Flutter - When you pull Instant Clock with DateTime, different time comes from normal

Tags: android, flutter

I have an app and I will just add hour to it. I wrote a code like this:

```
timePush() {
  var now = DateTime.now().toLocal();
  var hour = now.hour;
  var minute = now.minute;
  var print = hour.toString();
  return print;
}
```

The time in my country is now 03. But the output I got from the code is 00. So 3 hours back. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running on an emulator? If you are make sure to adjust the time inside the emulator settings accordingly.

Set the time settings like you would on your android/ios device.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Rian352 where time settings?

Comment: Set the time settings like you would on your android/ios device. That's how I do it. You can also set the time using a command line but for that, I would recommend watching tutorials